# Filtering HTML elements using JavaScript / Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm currently making a Chrome extension, and so I've been practicing a bit with it. I've been trying to filter the questions on https://stackoverflow.com/. First of all I want to keep it simple and simply hide all the questions, then once I get that working I want to only filter posts with a negative score.

My problem is that the simple version that simply hides all the questions isn't even working. I don't know what I'm doing wrong:

Example of a question:

[image]'

My `manifest.json`:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Example",
  "description": "This extension allows filter StackOverflow questions.",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ]
}
```

My `popup.html`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>SO Filter</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>SO Filter</h1>
    <button onclick="filter();">Filter!</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

and my `popup.js`:

```
function filter() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("question-summary narrow");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: When is your script set to run? "document_start", "document_end", or "document_idle"?

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an HTMLCollection of elements, an array-like object containing all elements with the specified class. See the [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName). You're using this method like it returns a single result - to hide all of the elements that matched, you instead need to iterate over the result:

```
function filter() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("question-summary narrow");

  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(x[i]);

    if (style.display === "none") {
      x[i].style.display = "block";
    } else {
      x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

<del>Also note for this to work, the styles have to be inline on the elements at the start, not in CSS. Otherwise, you'll have to check for their computed styles which is more expensive.</del> Now included.

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't filter anything on https://stackoverflow.com/, what can I do about that?

Comment: As I mentioned at the end, the styles probably aren't inline. You'll have to get each element's computed style. I can update the answer.

Comment: I've tested it myself and it works on the Questions page. If you're still having trouble, trying adding `console.log(x)` to see what it actually returns.

Comment: I have no idea what's going wrong. Adding `console.log(x)` doesn't actually log anything for me, nor does it filter the questions, but I know it should...

Comment: Sounds like your function isn't actually being run then... can you get any JavaScript to run on the page? When do you load the script? Perhaps the configuration of the extension isn't setup correctly.

Comment: I added the error I get from the console and my `manifest.json`.

Comment: Instead of an inline click handler, you can add the event handler in JS at the bottom of your HTML file, or in your script you can put it inside a `DOMContentLoaded` event handler.

Comment: I managed to fix it, but it still doesn't filter correctly. At least now it shows a `HTMLCollection []` with a `length` of 0... so something is going wrong there.

Comment: Is the className you're looking for correct? When I inspect the page, the questions have the class `"question-summary"` rather than `"question-summary newest"`. When I tested it myself I used `"question-summary"` and it worked.